# Gradient calculation for softmax version of triplet loss

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent, softmax

I have been trying to implement the softmax version of the triplet loss in Caffe described in
[Hoffer and Ailon, *Deep Metric Learning Using Triplet Network*, ICLR 2015](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6622v3.pdf).

I have tried this but I am finding it hard to calculate the gradient as the L2 in exponent is not squared.

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing the L2 norm using existing layers of caffe can save you all the hustle.

Here's one way to compute `||x1-x2||_2` in caffe for "bottom"s `x1` and `x2` (assuming `x1` and `x2` are `B`-by-`C` blobs, computing `B` norms for `C` dimensional diffs)

```
layer {
  name: "x1-x2"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "x1"
  bottom: "x1"
  top: "x1-x2"
  eltwise_param { 
    operation: SUM
    coeff: 1 coeff: -1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "sqr_norm"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "x1-x2"
  top: "sqr_norm"
  reduction_param { operation: SUMSQ axis: 1 }
}
layer {
  name: "sqrt"
  type: "Power"
  bottom: "sqr_norm"
  top: "sqrt"
  power_param { power: 0.5 }
}
```

For the triplet loss defined in the paper, you need to compute L2 norm for `x-x+` and for `x-x-`, concat these two blobs and feed the concat blob to a `"Softmax"` layer.
No need for dirty gradient computations.

Comment: @Naman if you are going to use caffe, you better go over the existing layers: these are your building blocks! the better you know them the easier your life would be!

Comment: One more thing, it's more about memory usage by Caffe. If I have to do L2 normalization what would be the way to do it? I can do reduction followed by reshape followed by eltwise layers but would it be more memory hungry than implementing the whole in one layer?

Comment: I was trying to implement this solution bu finding one problem. The paper sort of does a Euclidean loss. So after Softmax, do I need to give the output to Euclidean loss layer?

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I am still unable to get as how it can be done? With Caffe how can I give a constant vector as label to my Euclidean loss? It's going to contsant vector (0,1) for all examples. Is there any way of doing it in Caffe.

Answer (score 2):

This is a math question, but here it goes.   The first equation is what you're used to, and the second is what you do when it's not squared.

[image: Derivation of norm]

Comment: can you not divide by 2 the nominator and the denominator?

Comment: of course you can, I just included the entire thing, to avoid confusion