# Tensorflow, How can I compute backward pass for a given forward function

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I want to construct an L2-norm layer in `Caffe` style (well, I actually want to use `Tensorflow` in a `pycaffe` layer, since using `CUDA` to write `.cu` files in `Caffe` is an onerous task.)

**Forward pass:**
- input(x): n-D array
- output(y): n-D array that has the same shape of input
- operation:

```py
y = x / sqrt(sum(x^2,axis=(0,1))) # channel wise L2 normalization
```

---

```py
class L2NormLayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.eps = 1e-12
        self.sess = tf.Session()

    def forward(self, in_x):
        self.x = tf.constant(in_x)
        self.xp2 = tf.pow(self.x, 2)
        self.sum_xp2 = tf.reduce_sum(self.xp2, axis=(0, 1))
        self.sqrt_sum_xp2 = tf.sqrt(self.sum_xp2 + self.eps)  
        self.hat = tf.div(self.x, self.sqrt_sum_xp2)

        return self.sess.run(self.hat)

    def backward(self, dl):
        # 'dl' is loss calculated at upper layer (chain rule)
        # how do I calculate this gradient automatically using Tensorflow

        # hand-craft backward version
        loss = tf.constant(dl)
        d_x1 = tf.div(loss, self.sqrt_sum_xp2)
        d_sqrt_sum_xp2 = tf.div(-tf.reduce_sum(self.x * dl, axis=(0, 1)), (self.eps + tf.pow(self.sqrt_sum_xp2, 2)))
        d_sum_xp2 = tf.div(d_sqrt_sum_xp2, (self.eps + 2 * tf.sqrt(self.sum_xp2)))
        d_xp2 = tf.ones_like(self.xp2) * d_sum_xp2
        d_x2 = 2 * self.x * d_xp2
        d_x = d_x1 + d_x2

        return self.sess.run(d_x)
```

As commented in the code, how can I calcualte the gradient of the forward pass function by using `Tensorflow` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best strategy would be to use existing caffe layers to achieve your goal.
First, use [`"Reduction"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/reduction.html) layer to compute the sq. L2 norm of `x`:

```
layer {
  name: "norm_x_sq"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "x"
  top: "norm_x_sq"
  reduction_param { operation: SUMSQ axis: 1 }
}
```

Use [`"Power"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/power.html) layer to take the square root of the norm and compute its reciprocal:

```
layer {
  name: "norm_x-1"
  type: "Power"
  bottom: "norm_x_sq"
  top: "norm_x-1"
  power_param { power: -0.5 }
}
```

Once you have the denominator, you need to [`"Tile"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/tile.html) it back to the same `shape` as `x`:

```
layer {
  name: "denom"
  type: "Tile"
  bottom: "norm_x-1"
  top: "denom"
  tile_param { axis:1 tiles: N } # here you'll have to manually put the target dimension N
}
```

Finally, use [`"Eltwise"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/eltwise.html) layer to normalize `x`:

```
layer {
  name: "x_norm"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "x"
  bottom: "denom"
  top: "x_norm"
  eltwise_param { operation: PROD }
}
```

Some additional notes:
1. Dividing by the norm might be numerically unstable if the norm is very little. You might want to consider adding a tiny constant to `"norm_x_sq"` before taking the reciprocal of the square root. You can do that using existing layers as well.
2. This example showed how to normalize according to `axis=1` dimension. Depending how your vectors are arranged in the blob, you might be able to use [`"Scale"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/scale.html) layer for the division instead of tile+eltwise.
3. You might also find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36283863/1714410) useful.

Comment: Hi @Shai, thank you for your neat solution. This is the most efficient solution I currently have. I will try to deploy this as soon as possible. However, I am seeking for a more general way to enable GPU in my own layer. One of the problems of using caffe's builtin layers is that my function cannot grow too complex, for example, a customized activation layer that needs to select elements satisfying a certain condition. Therefore, I am looking for a way to leverage auto-gradient feature of Tensorflow in my pycaffe layer.

Comment: I noticed that your implementation has some difference with mine. The reduction gives a result with shape (1,0,0,0), however, I want to have only the channel-wise L2 which is expected to give a result with shape (0,0,W,H).